# Xpath not working in Perl but works in browser

Tags: perl, parsing, xpath

I am trying to fetch the data from the table cell with this:

```
my $data = $tree->findvalue('(.//table[@class="tab openTab"]/tbody/tr/td/text())[1]');
```

This XPath (.//table[@class="tab openTab"]/tbody/tr/td/text())[1] works perfect when I test it in browser with $x('(.//table[@class="tab openTab"]/tbody/tr/td/text())[1]') but refuses to work in Perl (no data returned). The Perl code is fine because I fetch some other data with the same $tree from the same source.

How could it be?

Comment: Doesn't work for what data?

Comment: The data is very simple - shop's open time for each day of week, for exampe "09:00 - 21:00"

Comment: `$tree->findvalue('(.//table[@class="tab openTab"]/tbody/tr/td/text())[1]')` will definitely return nothing (undef? empty string?) for `09:00 - 21:00`. That shouldn't be surprising due to the total lack of any `table`, `tbody`, `tr` and `td` elements in that document.

Comment: Can you please explain why and why it works from the console with $x(...) then?

Comment: If that's your document, it definitely won't work from there either, for the same reasons. If you ask to match "stuff within a table", and there is no table, you're not going to get anything.

Comment: Seems I've been misunderstood, the document is ok. it contains the table, tbody, tr's etc. I mean that "09:00-21:00" is my target data written in the table cell. The problem is definitely not in the document because my XPath works in the console.

Comment: Let me try it more explicitely: share the data.

Comment: I tried it with `<html> <head><title></title></head> <body> <table class="tab openTab"> <tbody> <tr><td>09:00 - 21:00</td> </table> </body> </html>` and `XML::LibXML`. It returns the hours as expected.

Comment: Guys, I am very sorry for taking your time, Ikegami was right, there was no tbody tag in the source, and seems when I've been testing it in the console it was just skipped.

Comment: Your browser adds the implied TBODY element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, every table has a TBODY element, even if its start and end tag are both omitted. Your browser knows this, and creates a TBODY in its object tree.

XML::LibXML is just an XML parser. Unlike SGML on which HTML is based, XML has no concept of implied elements. XML::LibXML has support for HTML syntax, but whether parsing XML or HTML, the document the parser returns is a representation of what's actually in the file. No TBODY element is added if none is found in the file.

So `table/tbody/tr/td` is suitable for the tree created by your browser, but it's not suitable for the file provided to XML::LibXML.